# Visual Studio 2010 and discovery of advantage server error

Tags: advantage-database-server

I installed VS 2010 on a Windows 7 64 bit machine.  When I try and connect to an advantage database through the server explorer using the Advanatage OLEDB driver I get a cannot discover advantage database server error.  I can connect to the database using the ARC just fine.  I was able to connect in VS 2008 just fine.  Any ideas on why I can't connect in VS 2010?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to connect with "local server", then be sure that your connection string contains `"ServerType=ADS_LOCAL_SERVER;"`.  If using Advantage Database Server (remote server), then [`this link`](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?Key=17&RefNo=020806-1486) might have some ideas that help. It discusses various ways to provide the IP address and port number if discovery is failing.  For example, you can include the port number in the connection path:  `\\servername:6262\path\dictionary.add`.

Comment: The above should work, but if not, is your ADS.ini on the path?  Are your DLLs on the path?  Calling it from Arc (assuming you are running it from the installation directory), a lot of the needed files are in the ARC directory.  Advantage looks in the directory of the application that is calling it, looking for DLLs and ADS.INI, then follows the path.  Since things work in ARC and not in VS, it is possible VS isn't looking at the same info as ARC.